# PHP: Determine regex order of importance

Tags: php, regex, string

I've hit a snag in a syntax highlighter I've been working on. PHP supports strings contained between both `""` and `''`. Unlike C#, which is more easily controlled by only allowing `""`, with the option `@` for automatically escaping the string.

If I have two strings, like so:

```
$code = "print( \"<div class='test'>content?div><div class='test'>content</div>\" );";
```

If I echo $code, I will get:

```
print( "<div class='test'>content?div><div class='test'>content</div>" );
```

Here's my problem. When I parse content between the starting quote and ending quote, I removed such content to be put back later (so I don't cross highlight), using a clipboard tool (just copy paste). **I have it setup to parse content between `''` first** using regex. The end result (after both string types) will look like so:

```
print( "<div class=>content?div><div class=>content</div>" );
```

How can I modify my regex to look back (from start) and forward (from end) to look for the topmost string delimeter (`'` or `"`). It's hard to explain, hopefully someone gets it, otherwise I'll just have to live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with regular expressions; they are not powerful enough to deal with recursion.  They cannot close nested parentheses correctly, they cannot close nested quotes correctly.  You need a push-down automata (or a context-free language) at the least for this kind of functionality.